# The nut embedded in the front top strut mount is spinning with the bolt. What are my options for getting it out?

Tags: golf, shock-absorber, seized-engine

I'm replacing the front suspension on an Volkswagen MK5 GTi.

There's three bolts which secure the top strut mount to the engine chasis.  I've removed two of them, but the third one is spinning without loosening.  [There's a nut built-in to the strut mount](https://store.034motorsport.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/3/034motorsport-strut-mount-density-line-mqb-audi-8v-a3-s3-volkswagen-gti-golf-r-034-601-1007-sd-3.jpg) which I am struggling to find a way to grip, due to very limited space in the wheel arch.  It's so close to the rubber of the mount that I can't get a socket over it.  Open end of a spanner fits, but can't grip due to limited space.

Do I have any options other than angle grinding the head of the bolt off?

[Here's a picture of the strut assembly](https://workshop-manuals.com/volkswagen/golf-mk5/images/golf-mk5-346.png), bolts #9 on the diagram are the ones in question.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I’d just cut or grind the bolt off, why waste time trying to save something you’re going to replace?

Answer (score 1):

I would either drill the bolt head off or grind it off , usually go for drilling as there are no sparks flying around.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine if this is the best option, as there's no photo of the underside of your suspension showing the placement of the nuts, but this sort of problem may lend itself to the use of a basin wrench:

[image: basin wrench]

The jaws of the wrench will rotate up to 90° to the shaft and is designed to work in tight spaces under a sink (or basin) where conventional wrenches will not work.

Another option would be a crowfoot wrench which also works in limited space areas. This would require an extension on your ratchet with sufficient reach to get to the suspension tower.

[image: crowfoot wrench]